# SQL Query: Joining of Two tables Using LEFT OR RIGHT OR INNER JOIN only - Need NULL values

Tags: sql, zoho

Clause to follow is, I have provision to use LEFT or RIGHT OR INNER JOIN and GROUP_CONTACT only.

I have two tables as follows:

Collections table:

```
LoanID  Transacction-Date   Amount
12345   05/02/17             500
12345   06/02/17             1000
```

OverdueClollection Table:

```
LoanID  Transaction-Date  Amount
12345   07/02/17          250
12345   09/02/17          900
```

If I join them with the following query suppose,

```
SELECT
     c.LoanID,
     date(c.TransactionDate),
     date(d.TransactionDate),
     c.Amount,
     d.Amount FROM Collections c LEFT JOIN Overduecollection d ON c.LoanID  = d.LoanID
```

I am getting the following results

```
c.LoanID c.TransactionDate  d.TransactionDate   c.Amount   d.Amount
12345     05 Feb, 2018     09 Feb, 2018         500.0      900.0
12345     05 Feb, 2018     07 Feb, 2018         500.0      250.0
12345     06 Jan, 2018     09 Feb, 2018         1000.0     900.0
12345     06 Jan, 2018     07 Feb, 2018         1000.0     250.0
```

But I need the results as follows:

```
c.LoanID c.TransactionDate) d.TransactionDate   c.Amount    d.Amount
12345    05 Feb, 2018                            500.0  
12345                       09 Feb, 2018                    250.0
12345    06 Jan, 2018                           1000.0  
12345                       07 Feb, 2018                    900.0
```

is it possible by considering the above clause? if so what is the way it needs to be done? or other best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You're really looking for a union query, not a join.

```
SELECT
    LoanID = c.LoanID,
    C_TransactionDate = date(c.TransactionDate),
    D_TransactionDate = NULL,
    C_Amount = c.Amount,
    D_Amount = NULL 
FROM 
    Collections c 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    LoanID = d.LoanID,
    C_TransactionDate = NULL,
    D_TransactionDate = date(d.TransactionDate),
    C_Amount = NULL,
    D_Amount = d.Amount 
FROM 
    Overduecollection d
```

Comment: Yes Its working as expected. Thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can't outer join using the LoanId because for all the records they are the same. instead you could do a full outer join on the transaction dates, which is what is different and this way you dont have to hard code `NULL` values

```
create table #collections
(
    loanId int
    ,transactionDate date
    ,amount int
)

create table #overduecollections
(
    loanId int
    ,transactionDate date
    ,amount int
)

insert into #collections
select 12345,'05/02/17', 500 union all
select 12345,'06/02/17', 1000 union all
select 123456,'07/02/17', 55


insert into #overduecollections
select 12345,'07/02/17', 250 union all
select 12345,'09/02/17', 900


select 
     COALESCE(c.loanId,od.loanId) as loanId,
     c.transactionDate as c_transactionDate,
     od.transactionDate as od_transactionDate,
     c.amount as c_amount,
     od.amount as od_amount
from #collections c
    full join #overduecollections od ON c.transactionDate = od.transactionDate --c.loanId = od.loanId


drop table #collections
drop table #overduecollections
```

output:

```
loanId  c_transactionDate   od_transactionDate  c_amount    od_amount
12345   2017-05-02          NULL                500         NULL
12345   2017-06-02          NULL                1000        NULL
123456  2017-07-02          NULL                55          NULL    
12345   NULL                2017-07-02          NULL        250
12345   NULL                2017-09-02          NULL        900
```

UPDATE:
the join should also include the loanId to account for tranactions with matching dates but different loanIds

```
    select 
     COALESCE(c.loanId,od.loanId) as loanId,
     c.transactionDate as c_transactionDate,
     od.transactionDate as od_transactionDate,
     c.amount as c_amount,
     od.amount as od_amount
from #collections c
    full join #overduecollections od ON c.transactionDate = od.transactionDate and c.loanId = od.loanId
```

Comment: Thanks alot, you gave me another way to achieve the required output. Thanks again.

Comment: @UM1979 also with this approach is more dynamic and you don't have to hard code null values
If this worked for you, please accept the answer. Thanks